# How to GET minecraft world spawn with commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like something opposite to `/setworldspawn`, a command that would return me current world spawn location.
I tried getting `SpawnX`, `SpawnY` and `SpawnZ` nbt data from a non-existing player, but it seems that this is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a few things and I'm pretty sure the only way is setting the player's individual spawn point to something invalid (like 0 0 0), setting `gamerule spawnRadius` to 0, killing them, waiting until they respawn (like [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354731/can-you-add-a-delay-to-a-command-block/354738#354738)) and then checking their coordinates.