# How do you make a command block so that when you die it activates a title

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a space map and I've made a fake entrance for intruders. I was wondering how to:

- create a title on a command block
- how to create it so that when you die, it is activated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use /testfor to detect the death of a player?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/202816/can-you-use-testfor-to-detect-the-death-of-a-player)

Comment: @pppery No, all the answers there use `/testfor`, which no longer exists.

Comment: I can't actually find any answer on all of gamingSE that uses 1.13+ syntax. So I just wrote down a quick answer and this can be the duplicate target from now on.

Answer (score 3):

There's a scoreboard type for this:

```
/scoreboard objectives add numberOfDeaths deaths
```

Now you can do things to players that have died: `@a[scores={numberOfDeaths=1..}]

And then reset afterwards:

```
/scoreboard players reset @a numberOfDeaths
```

If you want to delay actions until the player has respawned, try this: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/354738/171580