# How to play a sound when player respawns in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have tried looking around for the answer, but I kept on getting answers for playing a sound on death. I want to play a sound when player respawns. Any suggestions?

Comment: why wont on death work for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delay command blocks until player respawns?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354731/how-to-delay-command-blocks-until-player-respawns)

Answer (score 0):

For a solution, you can set up a scoreboard objective, deaths, with `/scoreboard objectives add deaths deathCount`. This will increment every time a player dies. Next, you need to set up another objective, health, with `scoreboard objectives add health health`. This will be used to check if a player is alive.

Then, place a repeating command block with the command `execute @a[scores={deaths=1..,health=1..}] playsound ambient.cave master @s` which leads into a chain command block with the command `execute @a[scores={deaths=1..,health=1..}] scoreboard players reset @s deaths`. This combination will first play a sound at every player with more than one death and that is alive, and then reset their deaths.

Hope this helps!

Comment: what version is this? the repeating command block command doesn't seem to work in 1.16.4.

Comment: i tried editing it to repeating command block: `execute as @a[scores={deaths=1..,health=1..}] run playsound ambient.cave master @s` and chain command block: `execute as @a[scores={deaths=1..,health=1..}] run scoreboard players reset @s deaths`, but the sound plays when the player dies, not on respawn which I want